# Php, out-pay of coins

Tags: php

If one were to make a "vending machine" and you would write in how much you would pay and if you paid £100 for a £2 item, then make it echo the amount you get back, and then echo the amount in coins (1p,5p etc. If you get my drift.) how would you do the echo'ing of coins?

```
$valg = $_POST['select'];
$pris = $_POST['pris'];

$r_pris = explode(" ", $valg);
$resultat = $r_pris['1']-$pris; 

if ($resultat<0){
    $slut_pris = "du skal have " . $resultat . " kroner tilbage";
} elseif($resultat==0){
    $slut_pris = "lige og plet på.";
}
else {
    $slut_pris = "du mangler " . $resultat . " kroner";
}
```

Comment: if ($resultat<0){
    $slut_pris = "du skal have " . $resultat . " kroner tilbage";
} elseif($resultat==0){
    $slut_pris = "lige og plet på.";
}
else {
    $slut_pris = "du mangler " . $resultat . " kroner";
}

Comment: Sorry to not that precise, but i'd like to know how to make the outpay of coins, if you got any idea how to do that

Comment: This question does not fit the general [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) style expected on stackoverflow. Can you please edit the question, adding the code you already have and highlighting any specific programming problems or algorithms that you need help with?

Comment: I have voted for reopen, since the edit makes the question much clearer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
<?php

$amt_paid = 100; //Fetch the user input
$real_amount = 2; //Pre-Defined Amount

if($amt_paid > $real_amount) { //Check whether the paid amount is more than defined amount
    $amount_paybck = $amt_paid - $real_amount;
    echo '£'.$amount_paybck; //You can divide this value to get a output in coins
    echo '10P'.ceil($amount_paybck/10).'<br />'; //Coins of 10
    echo '5P'.ceil($amount_paybck/5).'<br />'; //Coins of 5
    echo '2P'.ceil($amount_paybck/2).'<br />'; //Coins of 2
} else {
    echo 'Amount paid is in-sufficient';
}

?>
```

Comment: i've added what i got so far, i can get the rest amount, i just need a way to get it in a specific amount of coins, like a £20 note 2x £5 and such.

Comment: @user2119765 Ya so just divide the amount with the coin amount

Comment: Yeah i'd do that, but i need more than one type of coin, so i need to get a basic idea of how to do it.

Comment: @user2119765 updated my code, you can use precise float values, right now am using ceil

Comment: Thanks mate, done me a great favor!

Comment: This is going to claim that 10P change should be paid in 1 10P coin, 2 5P coins, and 10 1P coins, or 30P. Also won't allow exact payment.

Comment: @Wooble I just gave him the general idea, also if its a floating value, now that's where he has to decide how to handle penny